# How can I make sure that some file use the Visual Merge in Team File Service

Tags: version-control, tfs, projects-and-solutions

I'm new to TFS (the Service version at visualstudio.com) and I can't get my head around how to handle project files and the web.config file.

I know that I need to merge these files, but TFS always auto-merges them. This means that development paths and database paths are overriding those in my Trunk copy.

Is there any way that I can configure a file in TFS such that it never auto-merges and instead offers the manual merge method every single time?

I'm also interested in other peoples strategies for configuring their source control to get around such issues. On this project we're screwed and will cope as best we can, but the next project needs to run way smoother with source control.

Thanks for your help.
Mark

Answer (score 1):

There's an overall setting which controls this behaviour in Visual Studio 2012:

Go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Source Control` -> `Visual Studio Team Foundation Server` and uncheck this option: "Attempt to automatically resolve conflicts when they are generated"